# java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "dx": error=2, No such file or directory

Tags: android, gradle, groovy

```
def result = "dx --dex --output=${aarDex}   ${classesJar}".execute()
```

I used groovy to execute this code in gradle-plugin,but it give me a fault infomation in console:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:

> Execution failed for task ':app:fakeDexDebug'. java.io.IOException:
>   Cannot run program "dx": error=2, No such file or directory

I execute dx in terminal is OK.I am waste seven hours to solved it,but this bug also is running.Could you tell me why I could not to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The error means that the executable `dx` is not included in the `PATH` variable of the user with which you execute Gradle.

But anyway if you are in Gradle, I'd recommend not using the Groovy `String.execute()` method, but instead either creating a task of type `Exec` that executes your program, or if it is part of multiple actions of one task, the `exec()` method that has the same capabilities as the `Exec` task.

Comment: I am so glad to receive your answer , but i can execute dx in terminal.So i think my Path is right. And I only can't execute in gradle-plugin. I am will collapse.Oh my god .

Comment: maybe try "echo $PATH".execute() to validate what you have in your PATH.

Comment: Thanks a lot , I execute my code in serveral computers，but it is not OK.

Comment: I'm sorry, but without hands-on I cannot say more than that the executable is not found in the PATH.

Comment: I solved it . But i don't know why . I add a gradle-plugin's extension and asign dx'absolutePath,than it worked.

Comment: Of course it works with an absolute path, because then it does not have to find it in the PATH. That's exactly what I said.

Comment: Yes,it works. I am so glad that you answered me about this bug. I am a Chinese man and my English is poor.Now I solved it ,you give me a lot of advises.Thank you a lot .

Answer (score 0):

Use `dx.bat` instead of simply using dx in windows system

make a gradle task which will be easier like below

```
task makeDex(type: Exec) {
    workingDir '.'
    commandLine "dx.bat", "--dex", "--output", "E:\\output.dex", "E:\\input.jar"
}
```